# Why does fopen works without saving the returned pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, fopen

I wrote a little program to decrypt an, OTP encrypted, file. This works just fine.

But I realized that I forgot to save the returned file pointer when calling fopen on "Solution.jpg". As you can see, I am writing to the file pointer f. I am wondering why this code is working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILE_SIZE 4202

int main () {
    unsigned char key[FILE_SIZE], otpCipher[FILE_SIZE];

    FILE *f = fopen("otpkey.bin", "r");
    fread(key, sizeof(char), FILE_SIZE, f);
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen("otpcipher.bin", "r");
    fread(otpCipher, sizeof(char), FILE_SIZE, f);
    fclose(f);

    fopen("Solution.jpg", "w");

    for (int j = 0; j < FILE_SIZE; ++j) {
        otpCipher[j] = otpCipher[j] ^ key[j];
        fputc(otpCipher[j], f);
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `f` is invalid after closing it. So using it in any other function after that is Undefined Behaviour. UB means that it may work but it may also crash, or write to some other file, or continue silently, or any other undefined action.

Comment: Is `fputc(otpCipher[j], f);` writing to `Solution.jpg` ? I don't think so...

Comment: @LPs I think it does in the OP's case. Because `fopen("Solution.jpg", "w");` just happens to reuse the same memory for that `FILE` as the pointer `f` already references. So the pointer in `f` as used for that `fputc` is valid by chance.

Comment: You say it's "working" only because it happens to do what you happen to want. If you had wanted it to do something else, it wouldn't be working. It is doing something you did not tell it to do, so I wouldn't say it's working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found the answer using gdb.

So since I'm using `fclose()` before opening the new file, the pointer to the file used before were freed. This pointer could be used again and `fopen()` returned this pointer every time I ran this program.

So it worked just because there were no other file opened at the time I called `fopen()`.

This is undefined behavior and which can lead to other problems. It should be avoided in all circumstances (I did it by mistake). I just wanted to understand why this was working and fixed my code.

Comment: You correctly diagnosed the actual behavior, but be aware that it is in no way condoned by the C Standard.  It is undefined behavior to use `f` after calling `fclose(f)`. Call it a small miracle that `fopen()` returns the same pointer, certainly do not rely on it.  Also note that you should should also check the return values of `fopen` and `fread`.

Comment: Thank you, I know this is a bad thing. So I added this to my answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: +1 for both exploring the problem yourself using gdb and realising / accepting that "it happens to work" is not a good state to be in.